# What happens if I delete a question with upvotes?

Tags: discussion, up-votes

What happens if I delete a question with upvotes?

Will I have a penalty?

I mean, what would happens if the answers have upvotes?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

All reputation events from the post will be reversed if it's deleted, unless it's older than 60 days and has a score above 3, so if you've earned rep on the question you'll lose it.  There won't be any special penalty beyond that.

If the answers have upvotes then you won't be *able* to delete the question.

Comment: Although engaging in a *repeated* pattern of deleting your posts will 'flag' your account automatically —  to investigate the possibility of vandalism or other abuse.